# Same request but different responses from API when employing text-to-speech model on server

Tags: api, deep-learning, text-to-speech, audio-processing

I just trained my text-to-speech model successfully and I decided to deploy the model to the server.
I created an API on server where i request a text and I will be responded with an array which can be converted latter to an audio.
But i got a following problem and some questions:

If i request the same text, i will received the different responses through time. I dont know why it happens.

for example: if i using apache load testing on my api

```
ab -v 2 -l -k -c 50 -n 1000 -p data.json -T application/json -rk http://my_server_port
```

i will received different responses with different content-length like:

```
{"audio":[-7.423350325552747e-05,-2.1047946574981324e-05,9.325844075647183e-06,9.124634743784554e-06,-2.4708829187147785e-06,-1.0283396250088117e-06,-6.650391242146725e-06,2.5113597530435072e-06,8.37431798572652e-06,6.80460880175815e-06,-1.5071226755480893e-07,1.6641188267385587e-05,8.38576761452714e-06,-3.0194114515325055e-06,2.1294155885698274e-05,2.1820762412971817e-05,1.7816884792409837e-05,-3.483104592305608e-06,2.768885860859882e-05,2.2586074919672683e-05,5.095521373732481e-06,6.305455826804973e-06,7.078514499880839e-06,-3.3209059893124504e-06,1.9214032363379374e-05,1.783237348718103e-05,7.473254754586378e-06,3.893216216965811e-06,1.7985210433835164e-05,8.278251698357053e-06,2.6474042897461914e-05,1.2571800652949605e-05,1.2030096513626631e-05,1.4547090358973946e-05,1.241670543095097e-05,-1.476818283663306e-06,2.9840850402251817e-05,1.9380806406843476e-05,1.3785952432954218e-05,1.243586575583322e-05,4.494916083785938e-06,8.380916369787883e-06,7.806430403434206e-06,5.0648554861254524e-06,8.04245973995421e-06,1.2896463886136189e-05,8.21663979877485e-06,-5.516363671631552e-06,1.1092388376710005e-05,2.52366007771343e-05,7.738391104794573e-06,-1.235365925822407e-05,6.934483280929271e-06,2.192153078794945e-05,1.3452627172227949e-05,-1.0170933819608763e-05,2.5624203772167675e-05,2.9433518648147583e-05,2.3057138605508953e-05,-6.409165962395491e-06,1.971040001080837e-05,2.2817768694949336e-05,8.069925570453051e-06,-5.092448418508866e-07,2.441259493934922e-05,1.4206249943526927e-05,1.942902417795267e-05,1.315591453021625e-05,1.0455156370881014e-05,5.804651209473377e-06,1.50088089867495e-05,1.125138169300044e-05,2.6653533495846204e-05,9.925555787049234e-06,6.108827619755175e-06,2.224073432444129e-05,1.0918428415607195e-05,-1.4573974112863652e-05,3.271942478022538e-05,2.7123531253891997e-05,1.8350259779253975e-05,3.1701531497674296e-06,2.218450936197769e-05,1.9283193978480995e-05,3.13040186483704e-06,1.2619701919902582e-05,1.0842371011676732e-05,-6.987173946981784e-06,3.5264016332803294e-05,2.993772432091646e-05,1.5872346921241842e-05,1.2875061656814069e-06,2.0096982552786358e-05,1.577859256940428e-05,9.337199116998818e-06,1.1879182238772046e-05,-6.542350092786364e-07,6.403893621609313e-06,1.2006760698568542e-05,5.780885203421349e-06,4.710972007160308e-06,1.664119918132201e-05,1.778664591256529e-05,-7.5927000580122694e-06,1.787409928510897e-05,4.13107882195618e-05,-1.9296661776024848e-05,-2.4432834834442474e-05,7.22612776371534e-06,1.70267576322658e-05,8.565736607124563e-06,8.506499398208689e-06,-2.177361420763191e-05



{"audio":[-7.420518522849306e-05,-2.073943687719293e-05,9.503228284302168e-06,8.753058864385821e-06,-2.2817434910393786e-06,-8.694430562172784e-07,-8.566342330595944e-06,1.2815601166948909e-06,1.5979132513166405e-05,4.39063660451211e-06,9.161682100966573e-06,2.353204763494432e-05,5.621448053716449e-06,-5.149947355675977e-06,1.8312277461518534e-05,1.5471456208615564e-05,1.9066425011260435e-05,-2.2908733399162884e-07,2.2432970581576228e-05,2.008153205679264e-05,-2.5258216851398174e-07,5.138720098329941e-06,7.110614205885213e-06,-6.9790612542419694e-06,2.1201685740379617e-05,2.0385839889058843e-05,7.894856025814079e-06,-2.7666123969538603e-07,1.7583770386409014e-05,1.1622013516898733e-05,1.849187901825644e-05,9.53527614910854e-06,1.2597358363564126e-05,9.821907951845787e-06,1.9801344024017453e-05,5.4703418754797895e-06,2.9878745408495888e-05,1.5236278159136418e-05,1.8311324311071075e-05,1.3548414244723972e-05,8.351536962436512e-06,9.776646038517356e-06,3.719480218933313e-06,5.1014917517022695e-06,5.9505591707420535e-06,9.178397704090457e-06,1.0406990440969821e-05,-7.715407264186069e-07,7.423148872476304e-06,2.184179174946621e-05,2.6208858798781876e-06,-9.234613571607042e-06,6.285838935582433e-06,1.7693546396913007e-05,2.5428462322452106e-05,-5.639964001602493e-06,3.05264511553105e-05,3.2628930057398975e-05,2.2700047338730656e-05,-1.1032716429326683e-05,2.1791334802401252e-05,2.8623329853871837e-05,9.63995171332499e-06,-3.1881354516372085e-06,2.4671946448506787e-05,1.7006457710522227e-05,1.7634822143008932e-05,1.1291735063423403e-05,1.3884495274396613e-05,4.4872444959764834e-06,1.7274362107855268e-05,1.4909089259163011e-05,2.117067197104916e-05,4.9929199121834245e-06,8.474249625578523e-06,2.3428268832503818e-05,1.0199912139796652e-05,-1.2862687071901746e-05,3.154578371322714e-05,2.3897051505628042e-05,1.119890293921344e-05,7.408782494167099e-06,1.2067095667589456e-05,9.192099241772667e-06,2.529345692892093e-06,1.4922801710781641e-05,1.141111169999931e-05,-8.025640454434324e-06,3.312749686301686e-05,2.9743428967776708e-05,1.2637726285902318e-05,-5.348430818230554e-07,1.5626614185748622e-05,1.3584838598035276e-05,1.0890807971009053e-05,1.0727622793638147e-05,-1.6982817214739043e-06,1.042641724779969e-05,8.150030225806404e-06,2.6541424631432164e-06,1.288183921133168e-05,1.241666450368939e-05,1.9964465536759235e-05,1.673338715590944e-06,6.934636076039169e-06,4.3300377001287416e-05,-1.3977723028801847e-05,-1.9686389350681566e-05,1.644095391384326e-05,3.338007809361443e-05,2.6197794795734808e-06,4.0461658500134945e-05,-1.2347378287813626e-05,4.919712228002027e-05,-1.3089335880067665e-05,4.180472387815826e-06,2.3132655769586563e-05,6.600459073524689e-06,-3.65530354429211e-07,4.3468149669934064e-05,1.1303562814646284e-06,-2.4461316570523195e-05,4.001529305242002e-05,1.649748628551606e-05,1.423891808371991e-05,-2.5155468392767943e-05,-1.3476787898980547e-05,1.6860620235092938e-05,1.0472264193595038e-06,1.9239789253333583e-05,1.005693593469914e-05,-3.714154217959731e-06,2.1199713955866173e-05,-1.9121437162539223e-06,-1.5073590020620031e-06,5.1492752390913665e-06,2.1823527276865207e-05,-5.562197202380048e-06,8.526866622560192e-06,3.9139667933341116e-05,5.2409814088605344e-06,-1.1168492164870258e-05,3.004677091666963e-05,-1.3667826124219573e-06,8.320737833855674e-06,1.325245921179885e-05,-1.1443185030657332e-05,3.506239227135666e-05,-3.1136994493863313e-06,4.878381332673598e-06,-6.193377430463443e-06,-9.109250640904065e-06,2.2133541278890334e-05,1.4225409358914476e-05,-3.450880512900767e-06,2.1175712390686385e-05,-1.1907340194738936e-05,1.8063037714455277e-05,-1.3285753993841354e-05,-3.394313125681947e-06,3.0622471967944875e-05,-3.534668167048949e-06,2.5003388145705685e-05,2.8774020393029787e-05,2.3187438273453154e-05,2.5171757442876697e-05,2.7774323825724423e-05,-1.2312881153775379e-05,3.206680412404239e-05,1.4588803765036573e-07,7.6042674663
```

What are the reasons?

Comment: it's your model, you should know where randomness is employed to generate speech audio. only you *can* know this, because you haven't provided *any* debugging details. please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: i think you re right, i find out my model inputs random noises to synthesize speech so i think it's the reason why